How can I achieve the behavior of Apple Wallet cards using Flutter?
I want to create multiple images or cards using Flutter, each with the same design and behavior as Apple Wallet.
When any image or card is clicked, it should move to the top of the page, while the rest of the cards collapse to the bottom of the page. Upon clicking again, it should return to the normal design and layout.the main page once a card is clicked
i tried using Listview builder and Hero widgets but didnt work as expected
